# NPM package 'bin' script for Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, posix, package, npm

Cucumber.js is supplying a command-line "binary" which is a simple `.js` file containing a *shebang* instruction:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var Cucumber = require('../lib/cucumber');
// ...
```

The binary is specified in `package.json` with the `"bin"` configuration key:

```
{ "name" : "cucumber"
, "description" : "The official JavaScript implementation of Cucumber."
// ...
, "bin": { "cucumber.js": "./bin/cucumber.js" }
// ...
```

This all works well on POSIX systems. Someone reported [an issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/60) when running Cucumber.js on Windows.

Basically, the `.js` file seems to be executed through the JScript interpreter of Windows (not Node.js) and it throws a syntax error because of the shebang instruction.

My question is: what is the recommended way of setting up a "binary" script that works on both UNIX and Windows systems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Windows ignores the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env node` and will execute it according to the `.js` file association. Be explicit about calling your script with node

```
node hello.js
```

ps. Pedantry: shebangs *aren't* in the POSIX standard but they are supported by most *nix system.

---

If you package your project for Npm, use the 'bin' field in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin). Then on Windows, Npm will install a `.cmd` wrapper along side your script so users can execute it from the command-line

```
hello
```

For npm to create the shim right, [the script must have the shebang line](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/cmd-shim/blob/f59af911f1373239a7537072641d55ff882c3701/index.js#L22)  `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Comment: The issue was the binary script name ending with a ".js" suffix. NPM creates both a unix-friendly `cucumber.js` and a `cucumber.js.cmd` windows-friendly binaries based on the "bin" configuration instruction. Because of how Windows handles file "extensions", when one typed `node_modules\.bin\cucumber.js` it was running the `.js` file through JScript instead of the `.cmd` file. Thanks for the pedantic postscript ;)

Comment: I ran into exactly this same issue. I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require me telling Windows users to type a different command.

The JavaScript files pre-empting the npm-generated .cmd are executed in Windows Script Host; I'm hoping there's a way to leverage that to proxy to the Node-powered CLI:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113091/equivalent-of-unix-exec-in-jscript-windows-script-host

Comment: how do i make it execute by nodejs instead of microsoft jscript? even changing it to `node ./index.js` doesnt make it work. correction: re executing `npm link` seemd to work

Comment: I have the same problem as you with error ```ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\<module>\node .\index.js'``` .  And in package.json  ```"bin": { "<module>": "node ./index.js"}``` How did you solve it ?

Comment: Ok I added back ```#!/usr/bin/env node```even if it's for windows and it's working.

Comment: @YoyoS yep, that did the trick for me too thanks!

Answer (score 5):

your "bin" should be "cucumber" npm will create a "cucumber" or "cucumber.cmd" file pointing to "node %SCRIPTNAME%". the former being for posix environments, the latter being for windows use...  If you want the "js" to be part of the executable name... you should use a hyphon instead... "cucumber-js"  ... Having a .js file will come before the .js.cmd in your case causing the WScript interpreter to run it as a JScript file, not a node script.

I would suggest looking at [coffee-script's package.json](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/package.json) for a good example.

```
{
  "name":         "coffee-script",
  "description":  "Unfancy JavaScript",
  "keywords":     ["javascript", "language", "coffeescript", "compiler"],
  "author":       "Jeremy Ashkenas",
  "version":      "1.4.0",
  "licenses":     [{
    "type":       "MIT",
    "url":        "https://raw.github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/master/LICENSE"
  }],
  "engines":      {
    "node":       ">=0.4.0"
  },
  "directories" : {
    "lib" : "./lib/coffee-script"
  },
  "main" : "./lib/coffee-script/coffee-script",
  "bin":          {
    "coffee":     "./bin/coffee",
    "cake":       "./bin/cake"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./bin/cake test"
  },
  "homepage":     "http://coffeescript.org",
  "bugs":         "https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues",
  "repository":   {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "uglify-js":  ">=1.0.0",
    "jison":      ">=0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a solution to a similar issue.

My original plan was to have only one large `.js` file, for both the API and CLI (the reason is because I didn't know how to share variables between two files at the time). And when everything was built, I tried to add the `#!/usr/bin/env node` shebang to my file. However that didn't stop Windows Script Host from giving an error.

What I ended up doing was coming up with an idea of a "variable bridge" that allowed variables to be read and set using `getVar` and `setVar`. This made me have to extract the CLI code from the API code and add some imports to the variable bridge.

In the CLI file, I added the shebang, and modified the `package.json` of my project to have:

```json
{
    ...
    "main": "./bin/api.js",
    "bin": {
        "validator": "./bin/cli.js"
    }
    ...
}
```

Here are a few small notes that I think might help if Windows Script Host is still giving an error (I applied all of them so I'm not sure which one helped):

- Using only LF line endings seemed to help.
- It seems that `./bin` is the preferred directory for compiled files. I did try `./dist` but it didn't work for me.
- An empty line after the shebang may be needed:

  ```js
  // cli.js

  #!/usr/bin/env node

  // code...
  ```
- Using the same name for `main` and `bin` in `package.json` seemed to be an issue for me.