# Configure node npm package.json so that "npm test" works on both unix and windows

Tags: windows, node.js, unix, npm

I have developed a node.js npm module, developing under Windows.  Today I wrote some Mocha tests.  After many struggles, it seemed that for `npm test` to work, `package.json` had to look like this:  (there may be other options???)

```
"scripts": { "test": "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha" }
```

instead of what's in all the Unix based books,

```
"scripts": { "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha" }
```

How can I set package.json up to work on both Windows and Unix?  I'm assuming that Travis-CI runs Unix, so, should I link the build to that, it will blow up with the Windows version.

I found a two year old thread where somebody requested a feature for exactly this.  That thread seemed to die out.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396305/npm-package-bin-script-for-windows) seems to be close, but it isn't exactly what I want and, frankly, I can't understand the answer.  :-(  Can anybody clarify?

For the time being, I am going

```
"scripts": {
      "test": "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
      "testOnUnixUseThis"    : "./node_modules/.bin/mocha (I think)",
      "testOnWindowsUseThis" : "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha"
  },
```

Unfortunately, you cant go `npm test testOnWindowsUseThis` or `npm testOnWindowsUseThis`.  And it doesn't fix the Travis-CI issue.  But at least a person who downloads the module can (hopefully) see what is going on.

Any better ideas?  Am I the only person still developing under Windows???  :-)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've always been able to `npm install -g mocha` or `npm install mocha` and then just add

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha spec"
}
```

to package.json. That may or may not work in EVERY environment. I know, for instance, with lineman, you have to use bin/mocha. Also, if you don't find a way around this, set your test script up for Unix and then add a second script called "wintest" or something that does whatever you need it to do in Windows. You can name your scripts whatever you want. The default ones (test, start, etc.) can be used with `npm [command]`; any non-standard ones (like wintest) can be used with `npm run-script [command]`, and they will still work.

A little back story on how/why this works:

When you install a module globally, it's available on PATH (or whatever the windows equivalent is). When you install a project dependency, if that module has any binaries, those are symlinked to `node_modules/.bin` and when you run `npm run [some-command]`, npm helpfully adds `node_modules/.bin` to PATH *for that command*. So when mocha is installed globally `"test": "mocha spec"` uses your globally installed mocha to run tests. When it's a project dependency, it uses the one in `node_modules/.bin`. The one gotcha I've found with this is that npm adds `node_modules/.bin` to the *front* of PATH, so local binaries will always take precedence over global ones. *Almost all of the time*, this is what you want, but it's worth knowing that that's how it works (I recently had a bug related to this).

EDIT:

Not sure at what point in npm history this changed, but `npm run <script-name>` now works (don't need to do `npm run-script <script-name>` anymore). Possibly `run-script` still works as well. I'd expect it to, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: +1  This works on Windows and is a heck of a lot simpler than the other alternatives I've seen or tried.  Can't test on Unix right now but I'll trust you that it works.  Unless somebody posts an ever better answer in the next couple of days you'll get my "check".

Comment: Just hooked together all the Travis-ci hooks and this worked fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, just "test": "mocha" works for me on the mac and linux.

Comment: It depends what you name your test directory. Mocha might be configured to check for both "test" and "spec", but I think it's still good practice to be explicit.

Comment: this is making your package test suite dependant on the local machine setup, including the version of mocha globally installed, yes, it will most likely work, but not sure this is a recommended practice.

Comment: "script" should be "scripts" shouldn't it?
Using "script" in a package.json does not work.

Comment: `npm test` also works, there is no need to call `npm run test`.

Comment: The "run" part was for the separate windows/linux setup with non-standard names. You are right that you don't need it if the one command works in all environments.

Comment: Some others have mentioned this, but it's worth noting that you can install mocha as a project dependency (locally instead of globally), and this script will still work because of how npm executes scripts. E.g. if you're worried about the particular version of mocha being run...

Comment: You shouldn't be installing this globally - other users who run your tests will then have to install mocha (rather than relying on a traditional npm install).

Comment: WSL - (Windows Subsystem for Linux) in Windows 10 is integrated in Visual Studio Code which now makes it very easy to run Windows VS Code over Linux nodejs, bash, etc. with common file-system etc.

Answer (score 16):

> How can I set package.json up to work on both Windows and Unix?

If you

- use Windows
- dislike -g global install

...this is a working solution

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha.js"
},
```

**Notes**:

- putting `node` in front shouldn't harm, and can help on Windows (.js extension is not necessarily registered to the nodejus executable, unless you set it so. Could open a text editor, an IDE or (worse) windows scripting host, Internet Explorer…)
- Adressing the script directly saves you from needing a global install. (Not judging if this is a good practice)
- forward slashes help running under linux (obviously) and do work under windows (in this scenario. Also avoids a windows pitfall: backslashes if used, would need to be doubled – since they are interpreted as escaping the following letter if used solitary).

Answer (score 11):

Don't use global solution, I suggest you follow what the Mocha guys [say](http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication/1/03):

```
"scripts": {  
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha -w"
 },
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `npm i mocha --save-dev`

This will save the module as a development dependency and npm will automatically set up the executables to be used within the `scripts` object. If you want to use the executables outside of the scripts defined in package.json, you can install it globally as well, although note that you may end up with different versions of the package.

If you only install it globally, other people won't be happy if they try to run your tests (with the standard `npm test`)

Answer (score 3):

The new way with latest npm versions after 6.x, you needn't install mocha with `global` mode any more.

```
"scripts": { "test": "npx mocha" }
```

npx is installed automatically with new npm installation. It will search
`mocha` from `node_modules/.bin` or $PATH

reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx