# How can I run mocha with npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, mocha.js

I have implemented a testcase for my script and it runs pretty fine when I execute it in Webstorm with the configuration for mocha.

The name of my test script is adminTest.js.

Now I like to have a npm script to run it from the console or later from the build server.

Therefor I have made a script entry in my package.json

Here is the complete file:

```
{
  "name": "cdh",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "CDH connector",
  "main": "cdh.js",
  "private" : true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cli-color": "^1.0.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.3",
    "sync-request": "^2.0.1",
    "jslint": "^0.9.3",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.19",
    "xpath": "^0.0.9",
    "mocha": "2.3.3 ",
    "proxyquire": "1.7.3",
    "mocha-sinon": "1.1.4",
    "jasmine" : "2.3.2",
    "chai" : "3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec"
  },
  "author": "kme",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I start the script with `npm run test` from the console it leads to this error:

```
> cdh@0.0.1 test C:\src\trunk\scripts\testing
> node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec


npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v4.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! cdh@0.0.1 test: `node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js
--reporter spec`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cdh@0.0.1 test script 'node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/moch
a tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the cdh package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter sp
ec
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls cdh
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\src\trunk\scripts\testing\npm-debug.log
```

The `npm-debug.log` file looks like:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.7
3 info using node@v4.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info pretest cdh@0.0.1
6 info test cdh@0.0.1
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info cdh@0.0.1 Failed to exec test script
9 verbose stack Error: cdh@0.0.1 test: `node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:214:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid cdh@0.0.1
11 verbose cwd C:\src\trunk\scripts\testing
12 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
14 error node v4.2.0
15 error npm  v2.14.7
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error cdh@0.0.1 test: `node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the cdh@0.0.1 test script 'node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the cdh package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls cdh
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: glob should be in double quotes, example:
 
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha \"./test/unit/**/*.spec.js\" --reporter min"
}

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your script definition should not include `node`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec"
},
```

Or, if mocha is installed globally:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha tests/**/*Test.js --reporter spec"
},
```

See also: [Configure node npm package.json so that "npm test" works on both unix and windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013989/configure-node-npm-package-json-so-that-npm-test-works-on-both-unix-and-window).

*Update*: Ah is see you are working on windows, try changing the script as mentioned in the above post:

```
"testOnWindowsUseThis" : "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha"
```

Comment: I assume that there is a problem with my mocha. It allways returns with exit code 1 but no further error message

Comment: Maybe you can add some `console.log` to the `bin/mocha` script and/or the `lib/mocha.js` to see if and how they are called.

Comment: you do not need the `./node_modules/mocha/bin/`, npm scripts run with `node_modules/.bin` in the `PATH` - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path

Comment: If mocha 4.x or greater:                                                                    "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --exit"
  },

Answer (score 1):

Use `npx mocha` if `npm run test` doesn't work.