# How to run mocha test file from an npm scripts command?

Tags: node.js, express, automated-tests, mocha.js

I'm following the [Mocha test docs](https://mochajs.org/) to setup a unit test on some API routes.
In order to this I set up a `\test` dir containing index.test.js. Installed packages required by the test file including  `mocha`. Then specified the command to run mocha in package.json, `npm test`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./test",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

But when I run `npm test` from within the test directory containing index.test.js. The test doesn't seem to run and just show me:

[image]

I also referred to this Stackoverfow answer to no avail - [Configure node npm package.json so that "npm test" works on both unix and windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013989/configure-node-npm-package-json-so-that-npm-test-works-on-both-unix-and-window)

Question:

How can you run a mocha test file from npm script?

This is the directory location of the test file - `C:\Users\brianj\Documents\Projects\WebService-for-Self-service-Metrics-Portal\test\index.test.js`

This is the actual test file from `\test` called index.test.js with required packages already installed prior to calling mocha:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();
var sinon = require('sinon');
var request = require('supertest');
var _  = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();



// Global array to store all relevant args of calls to app.use
var APP_USED = []

// Replace the `use` function to store the routers and the urls they operate on
app.use = function() {
  var urlBase = arguments[0];

  // Find the router in the args list
  _.forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
    if (arg.name == 'router') {
      APP_USED.push({
        urlBase: urlBase,
        router: arg
      });
    }
  });
};

// GRAB all the routes from our saved routers:
_.each(APP_USED, function(used) {
  // On each route of the router
  _.each(used.router.stack, function(stackElement) {
    if (stackElement.route) {
      var path = stackElement.route.path;
      var method = stackElement.route.stack[0].method.toUpperCase();

      console.log(method + " -> " + used.urlBase + path);

      describe(method + " -> " + used.urlBase + path, function() {
      request(app)
        .get(used.urlBase + path)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200, "ok")
        .end(function(err, res){
           if (err) throw err;
        });
       }); //
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the purpose of testing the router dynamically? Just write the tests you need ad-hoc. I would never write test in this way, as you can see you need to test the test too ;P

Comment: I might be mistaken but it seems like after executing the script APP_USED stays empty as you don't call app.user anywhere. So the first _.each does no iterrations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try npm run test, if you are one dir above of the test directories?
Or if you are in the test dir then you can try `npm run ../test`