# How do you define npm test to run cucumber cross platform?

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, cucumberjs

When I was trying out Jasmine, I could simply add the following to my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine"
},
```

Then when I ran `npm test` from a Windows command prompt, npm would run my Jasmine tests.

However, with Cucumber-JS, I tried `"test": "cucumber"` but that simply opened `node_modules\.bin\cucumber.js` in my editor. I seem to have to use the following to actually run the tests:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber.js.cmd"
},
```

That seems very platform-specific, and I'd rather not make this difficult for co-developers using Mac or Linux.

Is there a value I can use for the "test" command that would work on multiple operating systems?

**EDIT:**
Note that my question is similar to [this one about mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013989/configure-node-npm-package-json-so-that-npm-test-works-on-both-unix-and-window), but not quite the same, since the answer in that question (using the name of the package, `mocha`), solved the problem, whereas in this case using the name of the package (`cucumber`) did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure node npm package.json so that "npm test" works on both unix and windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013989/configure-node-npm-package-json-so-that-npm-test-works-on-both-unix-and-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [a very similar StackO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20013989/3813891) and looking more closely at the contents of the `node_modules\.bin` folder, I discovered that using the following seems to do exactly what I wanted:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cucumberjs"
},
```

Apparently I should have been using `cucumberjs` instead of just `cucumber`.