# Equivalent of UNIX `exec` in JScript / Windows Script Host

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, jscript, wsh

I've got a .js file that's meant to be executed by Node.js on the command-line. I've got everything set up with `npm` and such to put the file into the user's path as a "bin". My problem is, because the file ends in .js, running it from the command line is shipping it off to the JScript-based Windows Script Host, instead of node, as expected.

I'm trying to write a JScript wrapper, to sit at `myprogram.js`, be executed by Windows Script Host, and ship off to Node.js. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like WScript's `Exec` command behaves like the UNIX exec command:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var proc = shell.exec("node .\\Library\\executable.js");

while (proc.Status === 0) {
     WScript.Sleep(100);
}

WScript.Echo(proc.Status);
```

This buffers the program's output, and exposes it via some sort of JScript `WshScriptExec` object.

I need a script, or a feature, or some other way, to hand *the entire terminal* over to the command-line script I'm launching. Most usefully, I'd like to replace the JScript process that's executing, with the process for the command that I'm executing (i.e. UNIX-`exec`-y behaviour.) Is there any way to do this, or some other way to solve my problem?

Comment: maybe this will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396305/npm-package-bin-script-for-windows

Comment: @wmz: yeah, that's all the stuff I've already discovered on my own. Problem is, it's not really an acceptable solution to rename a project, or to tell Windows users to use a different command name than everybody else in your documentation. Hence, trying to leverage Windows Script Host to solve my problem. /=

Comment: AFAICT, there's not an `exec` equivalent on Windows that will work the way you want. See [Is there a Windows CMD equivalent of Unix shell's exec?](http://serverfault.com/questions/315077/)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the .js suffix completely so you get the same unadorned command name, e.g. *executable*,  on all platforms.

Do so by setting bin in package.json as follows and npm will sort it:

`{ "bin" : { "executable" : "./executable.js" } }`

Source and further details: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin