# how to write an npm module that can be trigger from the command line like bower

Tags: node.js, npm

I don't even know the correct terminology yet but..

I want to write my own npm module to be installed globally and called via cli by its name, just in the same way as bower...

With bower on windows in the:

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

There are a series of files related to all the modules i call from cli eg:

```
bower
bower.cmd
```

I want to know how I can create my own module that would create my own versions of these.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396305/npm-package-bin-script-for-windows) will help. On windows, it is [still] important to add the shebang line at the top of your main javascript file - even though Windows doesn't really know what it means.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

This, in combination with using the 'bin' package.json field will tell npm to create a .cmd executable file in addition to the regular node module.