# npm looks like does not generate the correct wrapper for cli (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10-desktop

I use Windows 10, node 5.3.0 and npm 3.5.2
I did a cli, a simple hello world. This is its package of the module

```
{
"name": "helloworld",
"version": "1.0.0",
"bin": {"hellow": "hello.js"},
"preferGlobal": true,
"description": "Hello...",
"main": "hello.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "node hello.js"
},
"keywords": [
"testing"
],
"author": "me",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

The test works ok, and I install the module from its directory

npm install -g helloworld
When I execute 'hellow' appears its path and Windows asks me how to open the file.
npm wrappers are like this, from node_modules directory

```
"%~dp0\node_modules\helloworld\hello.js" %*
```

I don't know what is going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM package 'bin' script for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396305/npm-package-bin-script-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it doing more investigation

This is a good guide of how to make a complete npm package http://www.anupshinde.com/posts/how-to-create-nodejs-npm-package/

besides you need to add this line at the beginning of the bin script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

So, this is already done (and I am glad =) )