# Unable to create "bin" command for NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

My package has the following config:

```
{
    "name": "put-version",
    "version": "1.0.7",
    "description": "...",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "node index.js test.html",
        "compile": "babel src/index.js -o index.js",
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=4"
    },
    "bin": "index.js",
    ...
}
```

When people install this package they should be able to run `put-version`. But when running on Windows the script seem to be executed by Microsoft JScript, instead of Node.js.
I have already read this: [NPM package 'bin' script for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396305/npm-package-bin-script-for-windows) - But I didn't find a solution there.

I'm running the latest version of Windows 10 with Node.js 8.9.1 and NPM 5.5.1.

Comment: don't know but why you tagged javascript

Comment: It would appear Node isn't configured as the default application for running JS files then...

Comment: @DeepKakkar It has to do with JavaScript development. Doesn't it?

Comment: @James But in other cases it does work. I've tested opn-cli (https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn-cli). I also took a look at its `package.json` but it all looks pretty similiar.

Comment: @LarsKliesing well there is a difference, it has a sub key of `opn`, sounds like you may need to do the same e.g. `"bin": { "put-version: "./index.js" }`. FWIW if your package is a CLI package it's generally convention to prepend `cli` to the name.

Comment: @James I've already tried that. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @LarsKliesing did you reinstall the package etc. after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: 
I had to put this at the top of the script (index.js):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

So the beginning of the file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
// ...
```