# How do you run electronjs via npx instead of npm start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, npx, npm-init

I am trying to make an npm initializer with electronjs. According to the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-init#description), to make an initializer, your script needs to be started with npx.

Electronjs scripts [require that they be started with the `electron`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#modify-your-packagejson-file) command and not the `node` command. The problem is that npm init (npx) starts commands in `node`. I saw that the [`electron-start`](https://github.com/joshwnj/electron-start/blob/master/bin/start.js) package somehow achieves this, but I don't understand how.

Whenever I try to `const electron = require( 'electron' )` from the `node` command in PowerShell (instead of electron), `electron` returns a path string to the executable, and not an object containing the `BrowserWindow` or `app` properties.

Comment: Is it the shebang on line 1? I thought shebangs don't work on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. It's poorly documented and hard to find, however I found the line of code that causes electron-start to work on windows from within [npm's npx's cmd shim utility.](https://github.com/npm/cmd-shim/blob/f59af911f1373239a7537072641d55ff882c3701/index.js#L22):

> ```
> var ...
>   , shebangExpr = /^#\!\s*(?:\/usr\/bin\/env)?\s*([^ \t]+)(.*)$/
>
> ...
>
> function writeShim (from, to, cb) {
>   // make a cmd file and a sh script
>   // First, check if the bin is a #! of some sort.
>   // If not, then assume it's something that'll be compiled, or some other
>   // sort of script, and just call it directly.
>   mkdir(path.dirname(to), function (er) {
>     if (er)
>       return cb(er)
>     fs.readFile(from, "utf8", function (er, data) {
>       if (er) return writeShim_(from, to, null, null, cb)
>       var firstLine = data.trim().split(/\r*\n/)[0]
>         , shebang = firstLine.match(shebangExpr)           //<-- matched here
>       if (!shebang) return writeShim_(from, to, null, null, cb)
>       var prog = shebang[1]
>         , args = shebang[2] || ""
>       return writeShim_(from, to, prog, args, cb)
>     })
>   })
> }
> ```

According to npm on [`npx` (`package.json > "bin"`)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin), shebang-ing the `node` executable is "required." This is not true. While shebang-ing is required, the node executable can be swapped out on Windows. You can see here that the shimmer takes *any* shebang [(shim on wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20shim,or%20redirects%20the%20operation%20elsewhere.&text=Shims%20can%20also%20be%20used,than%20they%20were%20developed%20for.).

#### Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398567/10534510